# Clojure: Why does this give a StackOverflowError?

Tags: clojure

```
(reduce concat (repeat 10000 []))
```

I understand that `flatten` is probably a better way to do this but I am still curious as to why this causes an error.

Comment: I added a bit about `flatten` to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Leonid, `apply concat` is a nice solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because [`concat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/concat) produces a lazy sequence.

So, when you're calling

```
(concat a b)
```

no actual concatenation is done unless you're trying to use the result.

So, your code creates 10000 nested lazy sequences, causing StackOverflow error.

I can see two ways to prevent it from throwing an error.

First way is to force `concat` execution using [`doall` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall):

```
(reduce (comp doall concat) (repeat 10000 []))
```

Second way is to use greedy [`into` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/into) instead of lazy `concat`:

```
(reduce into (repeat 10000 []))
```

## Update

As for your suggestion about using `flatten`, it's not a good solution, because `flatten` is recursive, so it'll try to flatten all nested collections as well. Consider the following example:

```
(flatten (repeat 3 [[1]]))
```

It will produce flattened sequence `(1 1 1)` instead of concatenated one `([1] [1] [1])`.

I think that the best solution would be to use `concat` with `apply`:

```
(apply concat (repeat 10000 []))
```

Because it will produce single lazy sequence without throwing StackOverflow error.

Comment: Agreed regarding flatten. flatten is almost never the right thing.

Comment: @leonid-beschastny Why do "10000 nested lazy sequences" cause a stack overflow error?

Comment: @Thumbnail Because lazy-sequence is just a function producing another sequence. So, execution of such lazy sequences will produce 10000 nested function calls, which is exactly what stack overflow is.

Comment: @Thumbnail When you call `(lazy-seq x)` clojure creates a function which will yield `x` when called (or throw an error if `x` is not a sequence). It have no idea what `x` is. So, if `x` is another lazy sequence then you'll need another function call to find what's inside it. In our case it'll require 10000 nested calls to find that the sequence is actually empty...

Answer (score 2):

`concat` is lazy, so all the calls to concat are saved up until the results are used. `doall` forces lazy sequences and can prevent this error:

```
user> (reduce concat (repeat 10000 []))
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
user> (reduce (comp doall concat) (repeat 10000 []))
()
```